# Interactive Logic-Tree, Moving from Local Host to Online Accessible

Tags: javascript, web, localhost, dyndns

My name is Josie and I am working on creating a logic-tree process for a group.

I have a program and created this interactive logic-tree, and it currently operates on my local host (ex. http:// localhost / eSample. html). I would like to somehow make this "website" accessible by other people/computers, but am not sure how to do it and the explanations I have found seem to leave me with more questions. Things like Dynamic DNS and Port 80 I have worked with (and done per these instructions http://thetechnofreak.com/technofreak/localhost-online-apache/). But once I have done all those steps (which I have), then what?

It also seems to be contained in a javascript file, which I tried to work with in order to operate this logic-tree within an existing website. That was using Expression Engine.

I can't seem to find out how exactly this works... despite the many instructions I have read, and  I am hoping someone might be able to help me connect the dots.